# Grab a number from a text file using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that has lines of the format something like:

```
1   12.345   12345.12345678   56.789   textextext
```

Using python, I want to be able to grab the number that has the format nn.nnn, but only the one in the penultimate column, i.e. for this row, I would like to grab 56.789 (and not 12.345).

I know I can do something like:

```
re.findall(r' \d\d\.\d\d\d',<my_line>)[0]
```

but I'm not sure how to make sure I only grab one of the two numbers with this same format.

Comment: Extracting the last pattern on a line means you need `re.findall(r'your_pattern(?!.*your_pattern)')`. Or a more precise for this case will be `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d{2}\.\d{3}(?!\S)(?!.*(?<!\S)\d{2}\.\d{3}(?!\S))', text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a greedy match before matching your number:

```
>>> s = '1   12.345   12345.12345678   56.789   textextext'
>>> print re.findall(r'.*(\b\d+\.\d+)', s)[0]
56.789
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TH7fmX/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*` is greedy that matches longest possible match before next match
- `\b` is for word boundary
- `\d+\.\d+` matches a floating point number